# use grunt to concat ember files in proper order

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, gruntjs, npm

I am using Grunt to compile my javascript into one file.

In my `Gruntfile.js` I have a concat method

```
concat: {
        libs: {
            src: [
                'js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.js',
                'js/vendor/handlebars-1.1.2.js',
                'js/vendor/bootstrap.js',
                'js/vendor/ember-1.2.0.js',
                'js/vendor/ember-data.js',
                'js/vendor/ember-localstorage-adapter.js',
                'js/vendor/moment.js'
            ],
            dest: 'js/libs.js'
        },
        app: {
            src:'js/app/**/*.js',
            dest:'js/app.js'
        }
    }
```

for my file structure that goes:

```
js
 | --app
      | --controllers
      | --models
      | --routes
      | --views
      | --app.js
      | --store.js
      | --router.js
  | --vendor
      | ...libraries etc.
```

When grunt concats my javascript files it makes `js/app.js`:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('bookmarks');
});

App.Store = DS.LSAdapter;
```

How do I make sure the store gets loaded in `js/app.js` before the router, or does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files get concatenated in the order that they are listed in the src section for your concat rule. Order shouldn't matter in terms of store getting loaded first, but that's just an educated guess, so take that advice with a grain of salt.

If you did want the store line to come before the router, you would modify your concatenation to be like so:

```
    app: {
        src:[
           'js/app/app.js',
           'js/app/store.js',
           'js/app/router.js'
        dest:'js/app.js'
    }
```

That way app gets appended first, then store, then router.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also add a star/wildcard pattern anywhere in this list and it will discard any previously declared files that match.  Good for saying "include this first, and this last, and everything else between the two".

Comment: @Jon : I guess you should make this an answer. I almost missed your comment, and that is the best way to do it I believe